# How to draw text with transparency value with C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I create a from with transparent background color and I want to draw "hello" string on the form window with a proper transparency setting:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(150, 50);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);

    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected;
    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

    g.TextContrast = 10;

    Font font = new Font("", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
    Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D3D3D3");
    int opacity = 180;
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, color));
    g.DrawString("hello", font, brush, 10, 10);
    g.Save();
    g.Dispose();

    bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    bmp.Dispose();
}
```

When I set opacity to 1 or 2, the image text disappears, when set to 3, display dark black color, when set to 254, a little transparent. Anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Can't reproduce *"when set to 3, display dark black color"*, nor *"when set to 254, a little transparent"*. Transparency works correctly for me. Can you show screenshot?

Comment: Can you please mention which color have you given for TransparencyKey

Comment: In Form InitializeComponent:  this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Black;   this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

Comment: _bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);_ Huh? Make transparent pixel transparent? Makes no sense. Note that both MakeTransparent and TransparencyKey only work on 100% exact color matches. - Also: _The gamma correction value (TextContrast) must be between 0 and 12. The default value is 4._-  Also: D3~~ is a rather bright grey. Try a darker shade with less gamma!

Comment: I try: g.Clear(Color.Black); bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);  but nothing changed.

Comment: It should be noted that __you can't__ make the windows background shine through your text; anything semi-tranparent will only let the default window background blled through, which is black. - Form.Opacity may help, but it really depends ony what you actually want to do. Maybe you need to combine two Forms..

Answer (score 0):

I update code to:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
       
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected;
        g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

        g.TextContrast = 3;

        Font font = new Font("", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
        Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#191970");
        int opacity = 20;
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, color));

        g.DrawString("hello", font, brush, 20, 20);
        bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);

        g.Save();
        g.Dispose();

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

Output on screen:

[image]

Comment: Still very dark text on screen. :(

Comment: To TaW:  the background is fully transparent.

Comment: I meant the desktop etc doesn't shine through the text.

Comment: The desktop is shine through. My goal is  to paint semi-transparent watermark text on the desktop, hard to see by human. In above code, everything is ok except the bad transparency of the text, it's eye-catching.

Comment: It only shines through because the Form.Opacity is < 1. All the rest of your code is meaningless.

Comment: To TaW:  Yes, the Form.Opacity setting can adjust my watermark text's transparency effect. But When can I use the bitmap brush opacity attribute?

Comment: The better way to achieve is by using the WPF rather than Windows Forms Application. It Provides much more functionality than Windows Forms including transparency and opacity.

Comment: _When can I use the bitmap brush opacity attribute?_ Whenever you want __except__ when trying to create transparency in a Form, which is __only__ supported for 100% (TransparencyKey) __or__ for the whole form (Opacity). The bitmap you create has all the transparency and semi-transparency you want when you save it to disk or overlay it onto another bitmap..